# How to show a utility pin icon in vf page?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-design-system

I am using the below tag to show the icons

```
<button style="margin-top:-3px;right:0px;" class="slds-button slds-button_icon" title="pin" onclick="pinorPinned(true);" id="pin">
                <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="{!URLFOR($Asset.SLDS, 'assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#pin')}" />
                </svg>
     <span class="slds-assistive-text">pin</span>  
 </button>
```

And i tried with this as well

```
<button style="margin-top:-3px;right:0px;" class="slds-button slds-button_icon" title="edit" onclick="opensaveChangesModal('editModal');return false">
                <svg class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/apexpages/slds/latest/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#pin" />
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">pin</span>  
            </button>
```

But none of them works.

NOTE:

> THIS BOTH TAGS ARE WORKING WITH OTHER ICONS. I tested with edit(utility) and delete(utility)

I don't understand what is specific with pin icon.Please share if there is any solution

Comment: curious - if you go to: https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/icons/ and type in `pin` in search box, the icon displays as blank

Comment: So is there any way to do this?. Currently i am using apex:image for this. @cropredy